# C++Builder convert from ATL to DAX Smart Pointers?

Tags: c++builder

I am familiar with `ATL` and smart pointers for `COM` objects but C++Builder says it now uses `DAX`.

How do you convert from `ATL` to `DAX` ?

TIA!!

Comment: DAX is Delphi's ActiveX framework. Delphi-style interface pointers are wrapped by the [`DelphiInterface`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DelphiInterface) class in C++Builder, which operates similarly to other types of COM smart pointers.  What exactly do you need help converting? You need to be more specific.

Comment: `CComPtr` , `CComQIPtr` , etc..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What SPECIFICALLY do you need help with in converting those classes to DAX?  `DelphiInterface` provides similar functionality to those classes. Reference counting, overloaded operators for `&`, `*`, `->`, querying one interface from another, etc. Please be more specific in what you actually need help with. What are you confused about? What have you attempted that is not working for you? BE SPECIFIC!

Comment: `CComPtr<IWhatever> m_pi`;  `CComQIPtr<IWhatever2> m_pi2(m_pi)` for example.  How would you convert that to DAX?

Comment: `_di_IWhatever m_pi; _di_IWhatever2 m_pi2(m_pi);` When a COM type is imported, typically `_di_` typedefs are created for you, but you can define them manually if needed, eg: `typedef DelphiInterface<IWhatever> _di_IWhatever;`